# How to archive a remote git repository programmatically using Python?

Tags: python, git

I am trying to archive a remote git repo using Python code. I did it successfully using Git command line with following command.

```
> git archive --format=zip --remote=ssh://path/to/my/repo -o archived_file.zip     
HEAD:path/to/directory filename
```

This command fetches the required file from the repo and stores the zip in my current working directory. Note that there is no cloning of remote repo happening.

Now I have to do it using Python code. I am using GitPython 1.0.1. I guess if it is doable using command line then it should be doable using GitPython library. According to the [docs](http://gitpython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#meet-the-repo-type),

```
repo.archive(open(join(rw_dir, 'archived_file.zip'), 'wb'))
```

Above line of code will archive the repo. Here repo is the instance of Repo class. It can be initialized using

```
repo = Repo('path to the directory which has .git folder')
```

If I give path to my remote repo(Ex. ssh://path/to/my/repo) in above line it goes to find it in directory where the .py file containing this code is residing(Like, Path\to\python\file\ssh:\path\to\my\repo), which is not what I want. So to sum up I can archive a local repo but not a remote one using GitPython. I may be able to archive remote repo if I am able to create a repo instance pointing to the remote repo. I am very new to Git and Python.

Is there any way to archive a remote repo using Python code without cloning it in local?

Answer (score 1):

This is by the way a terrible idea, since you already have begun using gitpython, and I have never tried working with that, but I just really want to let you know, that you can do it without cloning it in local, without using gitpython.

Simply run the git command, in a shell, using subprocess..
[running bash commands in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python)

---

edit: added some demonstration code, of reading stdout and writing stdin.

some of this is stolen from here:
http://eyalarubas.com/python-subproc-nonblock.html

The rest is a small demo..
first two prerequisites

**shell.py**

```
import sys
while True:
    s = raw_input("Enter command: ")
    print "You entered: {}".format(s)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

**nbstreamreader.py:**

```
from threading import Thread
from Queue import Queue, Empty

class NonBlockingStreamReader:

    def __init__(self, stream):
        '''
        stream: the stream to read from.
                Usually a process' stdout or stderr.
        '''

        self._s = stream
        self._q = Queue()

        def _populateQueue(stream, queue):
            '''
            Collect lines from 'stream' and put them in 'quque'.
            '''

            while True:
                line = stream.readline()
                if line:
                    queue.put(line)
                else:
                    raise UnexpectedEndOfStream

        self._t = Thread(target = _populateQueue,
                args = (self._s, self._q))
        self._t.daemon = True
        self._t.start() #start collecting lines from the stream

    def readline(self, timeout = None):
        try:
            return self._q.get(block = timeout is not None,
                    timeout = timeout)
        except Empty:
            return None

class UnexpectedEndOfStream(Exception): pass
```

then the actual code:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from time import sleep
from nbstreamreader import NonBlockingStreamReader as NBSR

# run the shell as a subprocess:
p = Popen(['python', 'shell.py'],
        stdin = PIPE, stdout = PIPE, stderr = PIPE, shell = False)
# wrap p.stdout with a NonBlockingStreamReader object:
nbsr = NBSR(p.stdout)
# issue command:
p.stdin.write('command\n')
# get the output
i = 0
while True:
    output = nbsr.readline(0.1)
    # 0.1 secs to let the shell output the result
    if not output:
        print "time out the response took to long..."
        #do nothing, retry reading..
        continue
    if "Enter command:" in output:
        p.stdin.write('try it again' + str(i) + '\n')
        i += 1
    print output
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I use the Git command it asks me for a password. In cmd window I can type the password. How would I possibly provide the password if I am running the Git command using subprocess? I tried something like `--remote=ssh://username:password@server_ip/path/to/repo` but it didnt work.